# @ in password and Airflow postgres connection is failing

Tags: postgresql, airflow

In my Postgres password , there is a @  .Something like dba@123
in the airflow.cfg I have specified my DB password as

```
#sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:dba@123@postgresserver.com:5432/airflow
```

throwing error as

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "123@postgresserver.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

I tried to specify the password as parameters to the postgresql

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:dba@123@postgresserver.com:5432/airflow?password=dba@123
```

but not working .

Can any one help

Comment: That's a URL you are using as a connection string. You need to escape certain characters in URLs. Try `dba%40123`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you can set the DB properties as an Environment variable and then you can get them via function, like this you will not get an error.

```
# def db_props():

#     db_config = {
#         'host': os.environ["_HOST"],
#         'port': os.environ["_PORT"],
#         'db': os.environ["_DATABASE"],
#         'username': os.environ["_USERNAME"],
#         'password': os.environ["_PASSWORD"]

#     }

#     return db_config




and later in code, you can do this while making a connection 

    db_config = db_props()

    server = db_config['host']
    port = db_config['port']
    database = db_config['db']
    username = db_config["username"]
    password = db_config['password']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the special character or replace it with proper URL equivalent:
either use \ as a special indicator before @ that special character is next:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:dba\@123@postgresserver.com:5432/airflow?password=dba\@123
```

or use a url replacement character for @, which is %40 so the variable declaration is:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://user:dba%40123@postgresserver.com:5432/airflow?password=dba\@123
```